# Run jar file use Qt (QProcess)

Tags: java, c++, qt, qprocess

How can i exec jar app from qt (use Windows)? I know about QProcess, and i use that:

```
     QProcess myProcess;
     myProcess.setWorkingDirectory("D:\Programs\Qt\Units\MyJavaProjects\StackExp\target");
     myProcess.start("StackExp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar");
     myProcess.waitForFinished();
```

i show this message:

```
D:\Programs\Qt\Units\MyJavaProjects\Qt-Java\JavaQt\mainwindow.cpp:78: предупреждение: C4129: 'P': unrecognized character escape sequence

D:\Programs\Qt\Units\MyJavaProjects\Qt-Java\JavaQt\mainwindow.cpp:78: предупреждение: C4129: 'Q': unrecognized character escape sequence

D:\Programs\Qt\Units\MyJavaProjects\Qt-Java\JavaQt\mainwindow.cpp:78: предупреждение: C4129: 'M': unrecognized character escape sequence

D:\Programs\Qt\Units\MyJavaProjects\Qt-Java\JavaQt\mainwindow.cpp:78: предупреждение: C4129: 'S': unrecognized character escape sequence
```

And my jar file don't run. How do i exec my jar file from qt? Has qt other lib for my problem?
What do you think about it?

Comment: Or launch it using `start.exe` and make use of the filetype associations there. However your error message is trying to alert you to the fact that if you want backslashes in your string, you have to double them (`"D:\\Progra..."`).

Comment: What about start.exe? i have a one java file, executable jar file. I try do this, use double "\\" but don't run, and don't show error, what do u think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "run example.jar" you actually run `java.exe -jar example.jar`

```
QProcess process;
process.setWorkingDirectory("D:\\Programs\\Qt\\Units\\MyJavaProjects\\StackExp\\target");
process.setProgram("java.exe");
process.setArguments({"-jar","StackExp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"});
process.start();
```

Comment: Use this code, and i have nothing, and show message:

QProcess: Destroyed while process ("java.exe") is still running.

What's wrong?

Comment: add `process.waitForFinished();` or replace `process.start()` with `process.startDetached()`